# Dojo tooltip diaglog and dropdown button issues in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, dojo

I have a series of tooltip dialogs and dropdown buttons that in essence create a tree like structure to query data.

This works great in chrome and firefox, but in IE, if I select Disease A, then select Disease B, it closes all the tooltip dialogs and dropdown buttons and pushes the last one selected to the top of the screen and covers the Data button.

Code:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body, html { font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif; font-size:90%; }
        .dijitPopup {
          position:absolute !important;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/dojo.xd.js"
    djConfig="parseOnLoad: true">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require("dijit.form.DropDownButton");
        dojo.require("dijit.TooltipDialog");

        dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"
    />
</head>

<body class=" claro ">
    <div dojoType="dijit.form.DropDownButton">
        <span>
          Data
        </span>

        <div dojoType="dijit.TooltipDialog">
          Disease
           <div dojoType="dijit.form.DropDownButton">
              <span>
             A
              </span>
              <div dojoType="dijit.TooltipDialog">
                Year:
                <div dojoType="dijit.form.DropDownButton">
                  <span>
                  1
                  </span>
                  <div dojoType="dijit.TooltipDialog">
                    <strong>Sex:</strong>    
                    <div dojoType="dijit.form.Button">
                      <span>
                      Both combined
                      </span>

                    </div>
                    <div dojoType="dijit.form.Button">
                      <span>
                      Male
                      </span>
                    </div>
                    <div dojoType="dijit.form.Button">
                      <span>
                      Female
                      </span>

                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
                <div dojoType="dijit.form.DropDownButton">
                  <span>
                  2
                  </span>
                  <div dojoType="dijit.TooltipDialog">
                    <strong>Sex:</strong>    
                    <div dojoType="dijit.form.Button">
                      <span>
                      Both combined
                      </span>

                    </div>
                    <div dojoType="dijit.form.Button">
                      <span>
                      Male
                      </span>
                    </div>
                    <div dojoType="dijit.form.Button">
                      <span>
                      Female
                      </span>

                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
                <div dojoType="dijit.form.DropDownButton">
                  <span>
                  3
                  </span>
                  <div dojoType="dijit.TooltipDialog">
                    <strong>Sex:</strong>    
                    <div dojoType="dijit.form.Button">
                      <span>
                      Both combined
                      </span>

                    </div>
                    <div dojoType="dijit.form.Button">
                      <span>
                      Male
                      </span>
                    </div>
                    <div dojoType="dijit.form.Button">
                      <span>
                      Female
                      </span>

                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div dojoType="dijit.form.DropDownButton">
          <span>
            B
          </span>
          <div dojoType="dijit.TooltipDialog">
            Year:
            <div dojoType="dijit.form.DropDownButton">
              <span>
              1
              </span>
              <div dojoType="dijit.TooltipDialog">
                <strong>Sex:</strong> 
                <div dojoType="dijit.form.Button">
                <span>
                Both combined
                </span>
                </div>
                <div dojoType="dijit.form.Button">
                <span>
                Male
                </span>
                </div>
                <div dojoType="dijit.form.Button">
                <span>
                Female
                </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
             <div dojoType="dijit.form.DropDownButton">
              <span>
              2
              </span>
              <div dojoType="dijit.TooltipDialog">
                <strong>Sex:</strong> 
                <div dojoType="dijit.form.Button">
                <span>
                Both combined
                </span>
                </div>
                <div dojoType="dijit.form.Button">
                <span>
                Male
                </span>
                </div>
                <div dojoType="dijit.form.Button">
                <span>
                Female
                </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div dojoType="dijit.form.DropDownButton">
              <span>
              3
              </span>
              <div dojoType="dijit.TooltipDialog">
                <strong>Sex:</strong> 
                <div dojoType="dijit.form.Button">
                <span>
                Both combined
                </span>
                </div>
                <div dojoType="dijit.form.Button">
                <span>
                Male
                </span>
                </div>
                <div dojoType="dijit.form.Button">
                <span>
                Female
                </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
           <div dojoType="dijit.form.DropDownButton">
          <span>
            C
          </span>
          <div dojoType="dijit.TooltipDialog">
            Year:
            <div dojoType="dijit.form.DropDownButton">
              <span>
              1
              </span>
              <div dojoType="dijit.TooltipDialog">
                <strong>Sex:</strong> 
                <div dojoType="dijit.form.Button">
                <span>
                Both combined
                </span>
                </div>
                <div dojoType="dijit.form.Button">
                <span>
                Male
                </span>
                </div>
                <div dojoType="dijit.form.Button">
                <span>
                Female
                </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
             <div dojoType="dijit.form.DropDownButton">
              <span>
              2
              </span>
              <div dojoType="dijit.TooltipDialog">
                <strong>Sex:</strong> 
                <div dojoType="dijit.form.Button">
                <span>
                Both combined
                </span>
                </div>
                <div dojoType="dijit.form.Button">
                <span>
                Male
                </span>
                </div>
                <div dojoType="dijit.form.Button">
                <span>
                Female
                </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div dojoType="dijit.form.DropDownButton">
              <span>
              3
              </span>
              <div dojoType="dijit.TooltipDialog">
                <strong>Sex:</strong> 
                <div dojoType="dijit.form.Button">
                <span>
                Both combined
                </span>
                </div>
                <div dojoType="dijit.form.Button">
                <span>
                Male
                </span>
                </div>
                <div dojoType="dijit.form.Button">
                <span>
                Female
                </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Anybody have any idea why this is occurring?

Thank you for your help,

Eric

Comment: Can you post a running example somewhere? (like [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Here is the JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/ericall/F5CVa/    The formatting comes out a bit strange in JSFiddle, but you'll get the idea if you try it in Firefox or Chrome compared to IE.

Answer (score 0):

Would 
*cough* **dijit/PopupMenuItem** !!

The problem lies in the fact that a declarative tooltipdialog is not a childNode of the parentNode in which it is declared and that only one! by declarative this is possible though.. However, the dialog will hide once it looses focus and this event bubbles. So, everything is closed and the clicked button will open a dialog positioned by a collapsed and hidden DOM node.

Once you pop first dialog, you should see `<body><div class=dijitPopup>....</div></body>` appear. When a new tooltip dialog is popped open, the previous will vanish, consider this in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seeds/rk2da/). Dont expect nothing but this behavior from tooltipdialog - but instead use popupmenuitem:

```
require(["dijit/TooltipDialog", "dijit/popup"], function(dia) {
  var a = new dia({content: 'abc'});
  dijit.popup.open({popup: a, around: dojo.body()});
  var b = new dia({content: 'def'});
  dijit.popup.open({popup: b, around: a.domNode});
});
```